# Cake PHP - How to access a special Model found by Pagination?

Tags: cakephp, join, model, pagination

I have the following Code to get a special model related to another model related to actual object: (I want the Entry-model - in the Rubric-model-view)

```
$this->paginate = array(
            'Entrieslocation' => array(
                'conditions' => array('Entrieslocation.rubric_id' => $this->Rubric->id, 'Entrieslocation.subrubric_id' => '0'),
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'alias' => 'Entry',
                        'table' => 'entries',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => 'Entry.id = Entrieslocation.entry_id'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Then I thought I could get it by something like this:

```
$this->set('entries', $this->paginate('Entry'));
```

But the variable is empty, how can I access the Entries inside the Pagination in the view?

The Query generated by the code above is correct, I checked it by entering the query into phpmyadmin. So how can I access the result (only the Entries)?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you put `$this->set('entries', $this->paginate);` after defining `$this->paginate` as you have posted in your question do you get the variable result you need?

Comment: That's hard to understand - where does "Entry" come from? what associations have you defined

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The output by var_dump($entries); is:

 array(1) {
  ["Entrieslocation"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["conditions"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Entrieslocation.rubric_id"]=>
      string(3) "171"
    }
    ["joins"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["alias"]=>
        string(5) "Entry"
        ["table"]=>
        string(7) "entries"
        ["type"]=>
        string(5) "INNER"
        ["conditions"]=>
        string(35) "Entry.id = Entrieslocation.entry_id"
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must define $paginate variable below controller class. For example

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

     public $paginate = array();

}
```

Then in your action follow following patter to get the paginated result.

```
$this->paginate = array(
            'recursive' => -1,
            'limit' => 10,
            'conditions' => array('Your conditions'),
            'fields'     => array('Entry.*, Entrieslocations.*'),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                  'table' => 'Entrieslocations',
                  'alias' => 'Entrieslocation',
                  'type' => 'inner',
                  'conditions' => 'Entry.id = Entrieslocation.entry_id'
                 ),
            ), 
            'order' => array(
                'Entry.id' => 'desc'
            )

        );


$entries = $this->paginate('Entry');
```

To pass result set to the view use following:

```
$this->set('entries', $entries);
```

Comment: Okay, I will try this. My last status is that var_dump($entries); delivers the correct answer (20 rows in Array (Entry-, Entrieslocation-, User-model)). But some rows under the var_dump, I have my foreach($entries AS $entry)... This prints about 11.000 entries (so all!!!)... Why has the same variable different values in the same view? I'm confused