# Showing custom SQL results

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

**What do I want to do**

I want to list data that is pulled from the database with a certain condition.

**What do I have and what does it do**

I have a function that calls the data. When I `print_r` the data, it throws the correct stuff, so the query is executing directly. However, the display isn't working. It shows all the data in the database.

Here is my function:

```
public function myfunction() {
    $adminExtensions = $this->AdminExtension->find('all',
        array(
            'conditions' => array('location_id'=>'3')
        )
    );
    //print_r($adminExtensions);
    $this->set('adminExtensions', $this->paginate());
}
```

**What is the problem**

The problem, as stated, is that it doesn't list just the records with `location_id == 3`. It lists everything.

I have narrowed it down to the last line of the function, but I can't seem to get the right code in there.

My display file (`myfunction.ctp`) is a basic baked cakePHP index file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you looking for paginated result.

Comment: Check my answer for similar problem here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14575783/1201342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you currently have calls two different `find` operations. `$this->AdminExtension->find()` will return an array with all the `AdminExtensions` with a `location_id` of 3. The second `$this->paginate()` call just returns all possible results suitable for pagination in the view.

If you want to filter the paginated results you have to either configure the `$paginate` variable in the Controller or do it directly before you call `$this->paginate`.

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
  public $paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('location_id'=>'3')
  );
}
```

This will adjust pagination for all `$this->paginate` calls in the controller.

To do it for only one paginate call:

```
public function your_view() {
   $this->set('adminExtensions', $this->paginate('AdminExtension', array('location_id' => '3')));
);
```

Comment: Holy crap that was easy. Thanks a million. Explanation also makes sense.